# Docker stops responding with error "context deadline exceeded"

Tags: docker

```
Sep 27 06:07:26 ip-172-31-17-97 dockerd: time="2020-09-27T06:07:26.527041112Z" level=warning msg="Health check for container 7cd5fc57bea23e3869f172322331df0d320866ec65c76dc7d9944944ed2e3fd3 error: context deadline exceeded"
Sep 27 06:08:41 ip-172-31-17-97 dockerd: time="2020-09-27T06:08:41.367812575Z" level=warning msg="Health check for container 7cd5fc57bea23e3869f172322331df0d320866ec65c76dc7d9944944ed2e3fd3 error: context deadline exceeded"
Sep 27 06:09:55 ip-172-31-17-97 dockerd: time="2020-09-27T06:09:55.527277624Z" level=warning msg="Health check for container 7cd5fc57bea23e3869f172322331df0d320866ec65c76dc7d9944944ed2e3fd3 error: context deadline exceeded"
Sep 27 06:11:10 ip-172-31-17-97 dockerd: time="2020-09-27T06:11:10.798004911Z" level=warning msg="Health check for container 7cd5fc57bea23e3869f172322331df0d320866ec65c76dc7d9944944ed2e3fd3 error: context deadline exceeded"
Sep 27 06:12:49 ip-172-31-17-97 dockerd: time="2020-09-27T06:12:49.427768070Z" level=warning msg="Health check for container 7cd5fc57bea23e3869f172322331df0d320866ec65c76dc7d9944944ed2e3fd3 error: context deadline exceeded"
Sep 27 06:14:10 ip-172-31-17-97 dockerd: time="2020-09-27T06:14:10.368669952Z" level=warning msg="Health check for container 7cd5fc57bea23e3869f172322331df0d320866ec65c76dc7d9944944ed2e3fd3 error: context deadline exceeded"
Sep 27 06:21:30 ip-172-31-17-97 dockerd: time="2020-09-27T06:21:30.107523192Z" level=warning msg="Health check for container 7cd5fc57bea23e3869f172322331df0d320866ec65c76dc7d9944944ed2e3fd3 error: context deadline exceeded"
```

I see above messages repeated over and over.

https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/4509

Seems to suggest I need to update `containerd.io`
but when I do `sudo yum update -y containerd.io` it says `No Match for argument: containerd.io`

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the cause was?